# How to change position of dojo floating pane icon?

Tags: html, css, dojo

I'm new in using dojo toolkit. I created a floating pane and add some tools in it.The problem is that the floating pane icon is located blow the page by default (bottom-left). I want to change the position to top. How can i change location of floating pane ?
[image]
[image]

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
   <link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.../js/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../js/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dojox/layout/resources/FloatingPane.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dojox/layout/resources/ResizeHandle.css" />
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="http://.../arcgis_js_api/library/3.13/3.13/dojox/layout/resources/ExpandoPane.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsapi_vsdoc10_v38.js"></script>
<style>
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
  }

  #mymap{
    padding:0;
  }



</style>

   <script>

       require(["dojo/parser", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/map", "dijit/Toolbar", "esri/dijit/Legend", "esri/dijit/OverviewMap", "esri/dijit/Scalebar", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dijit/registry", "dojox/layout/ExpandoPane", "dojox/layout/FloatingPane", "dijit/form/Button"], function (parser, Infotemplate) {
           parser.parse();

           var sr = new esri.SpatialReference({ wkid: 4326 });
           //create the extent object
           var startExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(-88.27, 17.47, -88.16, 17.54, sr);
           //create the map object and load it into the 'mymap'
           var map = new esri.Map("mymap", { extent: startExtent });

           var layer3 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/bestaurants/MapServer/0", { outFields: ["*"] });

           var layer2 = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/bestaurants/MapServer/1", { outFields: ["*"] });
           //var layer = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://...:6080/arcgis/rest/services/bestaurants/MapServer");

           map.addLayer(layer2);
           map.addLayer(layer3);


           // legend
           var legend = new esri.dijit.Legend({ map: map }, "legendDiv");
           legend.startup();
           //overview
           var overview = new esri.dijit.OverviewMap({ map: map });
           overview.startup();
           //scalbar
           var scalebar = new esri.dijit.Scalebar({ map: map });
           //navigation toolbar

           require(["esri/toolbars/navigation", "dojo/on", "dojo/parser", "dijit/registry", "dijit/Toolbar", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "dijit/form/button"],
        function (Navigation, on, parser, registry) {
            parser.parse();
            navToolbar = new Navigation(map);
            on(navToolbar, "onExtentHistoryChange", extentHistoryChangeHandler);

            registry.byId("zoomin").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_IN);
            });

            registry.byId("zoomout").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.activate(Navigation.ZOOM_OUT);
            });

            registry.byId("zoomfullext").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.zoomToFullExtent();
            });

            registry.byId("zoomprev").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.zoomToPrevExtent();
            });

            registry.byId("zoomnext").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.zoomToNextExtent();
            });

            registry.byId("pan").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.activate(Navigation.PAN);
            });

            registry.byId("deactivate").on("click", function () {
                navToolbar.deactivate();
            });

            function extentHistoryChangeHandler() {
                registry.byId("zoomprev").disabled = navToolbar.isFirstExtent();
                registry.byId("zoomnext").disabled = navToolbar.isLastExtent();
            }

        });


           var t = "<b>${NAME}</b> [${RATING}/5]<br>" +
"${WEBSITE}<br>" + "${DESCRIPTION}";
           //create the info template object and pass the template
           var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Identify", t);
           //assign the infotemplate so it applies on every feature in this

           layer3.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);







       }); 
   </script>

</head>

<body class="tundra" >



       <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'sidebar', gutters:true, liveSplitters:true" id="borderContainer" style="width:100%;height:100%;">

  <div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.ExpandoPane" title="Legend" data-dojo-props="title: 'legend', maxWidth:225, splitter:true, region:'leading'" style="width: 225px;">
   <div id="legendDiv"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="mymap" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'center'">

  </div>

   <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="top" data-dojo-props="splitter:true, region:'top'">

<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" data-dojo-props="label:'Navigation', onClick:function(){dijit.byId('dFloatingPane').show();}"></div>
<!-- makes example preview div big enough: --><div style="height:30px;width:100%;"></div>

  </div>

</div>




    <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/FloatingPane" id="dFloatingPane" 
   title="A floating pane" data-dojo-props="resizable:false, dockable:true, title:'Navigation' ,closable: false",
   style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:300px;width:100px;height:300px;visibility:show;">


      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomin"   >Zoom In</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomout" >Zoom Out</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomfullext" >Full Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomprev" >Prev Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="zoomnext" >Next Extent</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="pan" >Pan</div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="deactivate" >Deactivate</div>
    </div>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how are you creating the floating pane programatically or declaratively?. The above code does not show the code for the floating pane.

Comment: You need to change the style attributes of the floating pane `<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/FloatingPane" id="dFloatingPane"...` to position it correctly. i.e if you want it at the top then the top and left should be set to zero    `style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px;height:300px;visibility:show;"`

Comment: it does not work . it changes the navigation floating pane(image 2) and not change floating pane icon position when the floating is minimized(image1).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with your `dijit.layout.ContentPane` layout not listening to the `region: top` part of your ContentPane.

First, it should help to correct the general ordering of your layouts. If you want the "top" ContentPane first, place it first in your `dijit.layout.BorderContainer`. The documentation suggests that this should work without actual ordering of the divs, but since it is not, something else must be wrong.

Second, it doesn't seem like you are setting the sizes of your ContentPanes. Dojo documentation suggests you need to set sizes:

> Sizes are specified for the edge regions in pixels or percentage using CSS – height for top and bottom and width for the sides. You might specify a top region of height:100px and a left region of width:50%. The center must not have any dimensions specified in CSS as it resizes automatically to fill the remaining space.

Keep in mind that for regions: top, center, bottom only apply height styles not width; left and right panel only apply width styles.

See [dijit/layout/LayoutContainer documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout/LayoutContainer.html) (since LayoutContainer is a base class of ContentPane) for more infomration about regions and how they work.